# How to change the homepage to another url page

Tags: magento-1, base-url

How to change the current homepage to another url page I want?

Comment: Are you saying you only want to change url for home page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Log in to admin panel and go to

> System > Configuration > Web > Default Pages > CMS Home Page

select cms as you want Or change Default Web URL if you want custom page

Comment: this is my site http://myfavor.ca/ and i want to show http://myfavor.ca/marketplace/ as homepage how to input to the "System > Configuration > Web > Default Pages > CMS Home Page"
Thank you Minesh Patel

Comment: just add "marketplace " in Default Web URL

Comment: You Rock, Big thanks, How to be better understand magento ? any suggestion ? ,I am new, and the structure is complex , Thank you to point to me the The Way to Goodness.

Comment: You can accept answer if it works. if you are Beginner read Tutorial here
http://excellencemagentoblog.com/
http://inchoo.net/category/magento/